# Get selection string in IPAD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ipad

I have a text area in which we have some text and a "touchend"  event bind on this textarea. But while selecting text on Ipad it works only for it for first time touched select but if I am extending the selection part It will not return the selection string.

I want to return a string as I do selection of string. Below is the Link which I have prepared.

https://jsfiddle.net/22gc6gu4/63/

Any suggestion or help.

```
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}
$(document).ready(function (){
      $('textarea').on(" touchend", function (e){
          $("#textUpdate").text(getSelectionText());
      })
});
```

Comment: There is an error when you place the code in the editor here on SO. It might solve the problem.